# Python UDP socket.recv() stops recieving on Windows 10

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have a udp client function written in python running on Windows 10. I'm aware this is not production quality code but I'm only trying to grasp the fundamentals here

```
client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
client.bind(('192.168.0.107', CLIENT_PORT))
client.setblocking(False)
while True:
    try:
        data = client.recv( 1024 )
    except:
        continue
    if data is not None:
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

I have a server running on an embedded device sending out small udp packets periodically (udp payload size of 22). This client gets about 10 of these packets give or take a few then the script stops receiving the udp packets. The only exception raised in the try/catch block is that there is no data to receive. If I change to blocking the behaviour is the same.

`[WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately`

The server is still sending the packets, I can see them in Wireshark with the expected IP addresses, ports, and verified checksums.

The thing is if I add a send after the receive stops the problem goes away entirely and I can continue receiving the udp payloads

```
client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
client.bind(('192.168.0.107', CLIENT_PORT))
client.setblocking(False)
while True:
    try:
        data = client.recv( 1024 )
    except:
        continue
    if data is not None:
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))
        client.sendto("a_udp_payload".encode('utf-8'), ('192.168.0.108' , SERVER_PORT))
```

Is there something fundamental that I am missing here? Why does the stop working on the first snippet but not the second? Is there some buffer flushing issue?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have a firewall enabled on your Windows 10 box?  Does the fault go away if you disable the firewall?  (it sounds a lot like the behavior of a firewall that is blocking incoming UDP packets except those coming from IP addresses that a local program has sent outgoing data to in the last *n* seconds)

Comment: Also, when using UDP, you really should be using `recvfrom()` instead of `recv()`, unless you `connect()` the socket to a specific UDP peer (which you are not doing). That would also give you the sender's `address` which you can `sendto()` back to

Comment: @Jeremy Cheers for the suggestion. I didn't know this was the behaviour of a firewall. I'd opened the port previously for udp traffic when this issue first reared its head. After your suggestion I disabled the firewall completely on private and domain networks but to no avail. Could this be a router firewall issue? Although I was under the impression that the router firewall only effected the public network.

Comment: @Jeremy It seems I had to allow the python app through the firewall even with the private and domain firewalls disabled by changing the settings in 

`Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall\Allowed apps`

Answer (score -1):

Try to set timeout for the socket `client.settimeout(2)`